# I added *.aar to my project ,when I run it the project runs well but I get error when starting activity , how to solve it?

Tags: android, aar

The `aar` worked fine as a project then I convert it to library module and added it to a simple project to test if it works properly

the error :

> "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lcom/google/gson/Gson;"

I already added the `Gson` to aar .but it gives me this error when starting activity (which is inside aar)

[image: The error]

how to solve it?

Comment: Why are you adding an aar file to your project in the first place?

Comment: to test this aar first , I want to give it to some one as library

Comment: How did you add Gson to aar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is to add "implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'" to the test project , this solved my problem but I don't like it anyway ;)

Comment: My updated answer should explain why you need this.

Answer (score 1):

Use this dependency instead of *.aar file.

implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

Comment: I already added this to my *.aar
I don't believe it should work that way but I will test it let you know

Comment: Remove your *.aar file, only use this dependency it will work.

Comment: It looks like the aar is a custom library that depends on Gson.

Comment: I added "implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'" to project gradle then it worked fine but its weird isn't it? I already had it in aar

Comment: Dmarp - the aar is a project which I have been working on several months I need to use it , cant remove it

Comment: @tahaDev `I already had it in aar` You obviously didn't. How did you try to put Gson in aar?

Comment: I believe it is about using implement and api on gradle 
working on it let you know

Comment: @EugenPechanec - I added this to (library) project 's gradle and it worked there with no issue
- by (library) project - I mean project that I converted to aar

Comment: @tahaDev But how did you add Gson? How did you declare dependency on Gson in the library module?

Comment: @EugenPechanec - aar is a project which has gradle , I added it in project's gradle
then the project is working fine,I converted the module project to module library (it is easy) so Gson (Implemetation ...) was already there

Answer (score 1):

> The `aar` worked fine as a project then I convert it to library module

The AAR itself does not include any dependencies. It doesn't even specify the dependencies. The dependencies are defined in a separate POM file.

**If you include an AAR manually you also need to manually re-declare its dependencies in your own module.** Otherwise the dependencies are not added, classes will be missing and you'll get run-time errors.

When you define a dependency on a Maven artifact (like `com.xxx:yyy:1.2.3`) Gradle downloads the JAR/AAR along with the POM file, which in turn allows Gradle to download *transitive dependencies*.

Comment: thx 

I used api instead of implementation to aar lib gradle then test aar again in my testProject but still same error

when I added "implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'" to testProject's gradle it worked

- but it dowsnt look good

Comment: Does your app module depend on the library module (`implementation project(':library-module-name')`) or are you exploding an AAR file and depending on that? The first method would automatically package Gson to your apk. But working with raw AAR does not automatically process dependencies.

Comment: You can put into your question how your app depends on lib, so I can make a better answer.

Comment: @EugenPechanec this is a bit old but I encountered the same exact issue during my library development. So what you are basically saying is that if I import the aar file into the test project manually using implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", includes: ["*.aar"]) for instance, all the dependencies inside the library project DO NOT get added to the test project and I have to add them manually. And that ONLY a maven like repository can provide my library with all of its dependencies using a pom xml?

Comment: @AlonMinski Correct. A JAR or AAR typically contains only that one library without its dependencies. In a Maven repo, the dependencies are specified in a separate POM file, which is downloaded and parsed first when declaring a dependency using Maven coordinates (`group:module:version`). When building your own library, its dependencies are not bundled into the resulting JAR/AAR.

Comment: @EugenPechanec I see. Well, thank you! I either missed this in ALL tutorials I read or watched or it simply isn't documented any where... Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add all dependencies of your library (aar) to the build.gradle of your application as well. Libraries do not include their dependencies.

Comment: AAR don't include bundled dependencies, correct. Library modules can declare `implementation` and `api` dependencies that get put into resulting APK of apps that consume that library module.